# loop(repeat) script block until successful db(mysql) password

Tags: bash, script, mysql, shell-script, loopback

I have the following function

```
function executeMySql() {
  while IFS= read -p "$prompt" -r -s -n 1 char
  do
      if [[ $char == $'\0' ]]; then
          break
      fi
      if [[ $char == $'\177' ]];  then
          prompt=$'\b \b'
          password="${password%?}"
      else
          prompt='*'
          password+="$char"
      fi
  done
  mysql -u root -p$password -e "$1"
  ret=$?
  if [ $ret = "0" ]; then
    # Show success message
    printf "\e[32m\nSUCCESS: $2\n\n"
    tput sgr0
  else
      echo "Wrong password"
  fi
}
```

and I use it like this

```
echo -e "Enter your mysql \$root password to create the db"
executeMySql "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS Test" "Test db ready"
{
  touch /var/moo.txt
} || {
  # ...
}
```

But if user enters wrong mysql password he receives `Wrong password` message and the script continues but what I want is to loop the user password attempts until it's successful and then go on with rest of the script execution.

Any idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the working version of the function

```
function executeMySql() {
  local password
  local prompt
  local char
  while IFS= read -p "$prompt" -r -s -n 1 char
  do
      if [[ $char == $'\0' ]]; then
          break
      elif [[ $char == $'\177' ]];  then
          prompt=$'\b \b'
          password="${password%?}"
      else
          prompt='*'
          password+="$char"
      fi
  done
  mysql -u root -p$password -e "$1"
  ret=$?
  if [ $ret = "0" ]; then
    # Show success message
    echo -e "SUCCESS: $2"
  else
      echo -e "Wrong password try again"
  fi
  return $ret;
}
```

usage example

```
echo -e "Enter your mysql \$root password to create the db"
while ! executeMySql "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS Test" "Test db ready"; do :; done
```

Answer (score 1):

The `mysql` call isn't within a loop, so it will be called only once, whether it succeeds or not.

You can either make sure you return `$ret` at the end of `executeMySql` and call it using:

```
while ! executeMySql ...; do :; done
```

or you can modify `executeMySql` so that the `mysql` call is within the existing loop:-

```
function executeMySql() {
  while IFS= read -p "$prompt" -r -s -n 1 char
  do
      if [[ $char == $'\177' ]];  then
          prompt=$'\b \b'
          password="${password%?}"
          continue
      elif [[ $char == $'\0' ]]; then
          prompt='*'
          password+="$char"
          continue
      fi
      # Drop through when $char == $'\0'
      mysql -u root -p$password -e "$1"
      ret=$?
      if [ $ret = "0" ]; then
        # Show success message
        printf "\e[32m\nSUCCESS: $2\n\n"
        tput sgr0
        return $ret
      else
          echo "Wrong password"
      fi
  done
}
```

I have desk-checked the code, but I cannot easily do a code test, so I hope I have modified it correctly, though if not it should be a sufficient guide to what needs doing.

You could alternatively add an enclosing loop `ret=1; while $ret != 0 ...` within `executeMySql`, which is possibly clumsier, but needs fewer code changes.

Comment: It's not working but indeed helped me to make it work 10x